# Execute Runnable, Timeout, then Retry

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

I am using the Ebay API to place a bid on an item. If there is some kind of network error so that the API call does not return, I want to retry the call immediately afterwards. It seems so simple but I've been going round in circles all day. I'm not really experienced with threading. Is this how it's supposed to work or am I totally wrong?

Here is the Callable class:

```
public class PlaceOfferThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private PlaceOfferCall call;
    public Boolean isComplete;

    public PlaceOfferThread (PlaceOfferCall p) {
        call = p;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {

        try {
            call.placeOffer(); 
            return true;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the caller

```
    int timeout = 10;
    int maxRetries = 5;
    int retries = 0;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    PlaceOfferThread thread = new PlaceOfferThread(call);

    boolean flag = false;

    while (!flag && retries++ < maxRetries) {

        Future<Boolean> future = null;

        try {
            future = executor.submit(thread);
            flag = future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        catch(TimeoutException ex) {

            // no response from Ebay, potential network issues
            // resubmit the call to Ebay with the same invocation id

            future.cancel(true);

         }
         catch (Exception threadException) {

            // any other exception indicates that we got a response from Ebay
            // it just wasn't the response we wanted

            throw new Exception(threadException.getMessage());
        }
    }

    executor.shutdown(); // TODO
```

Comment: You don't tell us how your code does not work? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

> If there is some kind of network error so that the API call does not return, I want to retry the call immediately afterwards.

I'm not 100% sure how your application is working right now but here are some thoughts:

1. When you call `future.cancel(true)` you most likely will not be stopping the current transaction.  Unless you are using NIO calls, IO methods are not interruptible.  Interrupting a thread just sets a flag on the thread and caused those few methods that throw `InterruptedException` (like `sleep`, `wait`, `join`) to do so.  You'll have to watch the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` method to be able to see the interrupt otherwise.
2. I think the right thing to do is to set the connection and IO timeouts of the underlying http-client object and have it throw or exit with an error if there are problems.  Trying to kill it from another thread is going to be much more difficult.
3. In looking at your code I'm not sure why you are using threads at all.  Maybe you are doing other processing but it might be better to make the call directly.  Then you can tune the `HttpClient`'s  IO timeouts and handle them appropriately.